# "Simultaneous" minimum and maximum of a list

Tags: haskell

This function returns a 2-tuple with the minimum and the maximum of a list:

```
import Control.Arrow ((***), (>>>), (&&&))
import Data.Semigroup (getMin, getMax, Min(..), Max(..))

bounds :: (Bounded a, Ord a) => [a] -> (a,a)
bounds = foldMap (Min &&& Max) >>> getMin *** getMax
```

Example:

```
> x = [1..10 :: Int]
> bounds x
(1,10)
```

Is it more efficient than `(minimum x, maximum x)` ?

Or is there another way more efficient than `(minimum x, maximum x)` ?

Comment: The somewhat oddly-named `foldl` package offers a nice framework for doing a wide variety of things like this efficiently. For this simple case, another option is the `foldl'` function, and a third is a higher-order fold: `bounds xs = foldr go stop xs minBound maxBound where ...`.

Answer (score 12):

First off, your two functions do not behave the same. `(minimum xs, maximum xs)` dies when `xs` is an empty list.

> Is it more efficient than `(minimum x, maximum x)`?

They're both O(n), but the only way to answer questions like this is to benchmark them competitively. I think I'd expect the `foldMap` solution to be faster, as it makes only a single pass over the list, but let's find out.

```
import Control.Arrow ((***), (>>>), (&&&))
import Data.Semigroup (getMin, getMax, Min(..), Max(..))
import System.Random
import Criterion.Main

bounds1, bounds2 :: (Bounded a, Ord a) => [a] -> (a,a)
bounds1 = foldMap (Min &&& Max) >>> getMin *** getMax
bounds2 xs = (minimum xs, maximum xs)

randomList :: Int -> IO [Int]
randomList count = take count <$> randoms <$> newStdGen

mkBench n = env (randomList n) $ \list -> bgroup (show n) [
    bench "foldMap" $ nf bounds1 list,
    bench "minMax" $ nf bounds2 list
    ]

main = defaultMain $ map mkBench [100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
```

[image]

Tabulated, that's

```
100/foldMap 1.411 μs
100/minMax 517.6 ns

1000/foldMap 28.94 μs
1000/minMax 5.078 μs

10000/foldMap 488.4 μs
10000/minMax 51.56 μs

100000/foldMap 21.08 ms
100000/minMax 537.3 μs

1000000/foldMap 268.9 ms
1000000/minMax 8.989 ms
```

So `(minimum xs, maximum xs)` turns out to be faster than the `foldMap` idea, across the board.

Comment: The `foldMap` approach uses a boxed pair that isn't forced during the whole traversal. It's going to allocate more than the two-pass approach, *and* not allow the input to be gc'd. Lose/lose.

Comment: @Carl Interesting, thanks for this. Do you think a judicious use of `!` somewhere could fix the performance problem?

Comment: Might be worth trying with a strict tuple type instead of the one given by &&&

Comment: I don't think you can actually get good behavior out of `foldMap` here without using something like `Endo` over a sufficiently strict pair type. The `foldMap` definition for `[]` is going to associate in the wrong direction. You'll need to reassociate with function passing to get good space use.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark! I know `Criterion` but it does not work well on Windows (at least, the last time I tried it).